# adb device not found under Ubuntu console mode

Tags: console, ubuntu-12.04, adb

I came into this strange issue:

1) In Ubuntu GUI mode, open gnome terminal, execute "adb devices", attached phone can be listed

2) Switch to console mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1), execute "adb devices", the phone is listed. But after execute "adb root; adb remount", then execute "adb devices", attached phone *cannot be listed*

3) Switch to GUI mode again(Alt+F7), and execute "adb devices" in gnome-terminal, phone is listed again

So the problem seems to be that if I never list device under GUI mode, then I cannot get the device listed in Console mode. Anybody see this problem before? 
By the way, when the adb devices command doesn't listed the phone, lsusb can found the phone, so I guess in usb device aspect, things are good.

Comment: Make sure you wait for a few seconds in between `adb root`, `adb remount` and `adb devices`. Also provide information about the build your device is using.